# linker script and changing the flash address

Tags: stm32

I would like to ask the following a question: im using stm32g0xx microcontroller and i want to change the flash address in linker script automatically and not be forced to changed manually every time i want to generate an apllication image to let it run from diffrent address. what im doing i wrote an application and i wrote it to tow different address"0x08001000 and 0x08004800" to have the apility to switch to other application incase one of them is updated or damaged. it worked fine but i need by every image to change the flash address manually and i would like to ask if it is possible to changed somewhere else out of the linker script like startup.s?

```
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 8K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8001000,   LENGTH = 32K 
}

MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 8K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8004800,   LENGTH = 32K 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create two linker files and compile two times, each time with a different linker script and a different output binary. You will obtain the two necessary binaries. To integrate it on your project, it depends on your way of working (STM IDE, standalone Makefile...) which you did not mention.

As a side note, you should modify the `LENGTH` on your linker scripts, it will prevent the linker to place data where you have another application.
Your first application starts at 4KB (0x1000), and the second start at 18KB (0x4800), the lenght of the first application should be 18-4 = 16KB and the second `LENGTH` should be 32-18 = 14KB (if the FLASH total size is 32KB).

Comment: thank you for your answer :) i dont have enough space to generate two bin files. but  the LENGTH  i forgot about this point so i will changed in my linker script. at the end i generated two bin files, compare them and used one of them in my project with a lookup table to modify the firmware according to address, where it will be written to.

Answer (score 0):

You can write two different linker script and apply one or the other in your building enviroment (with the -T linker flag) or you can use a variable for your ORIGIN and pass it with -Wl,--defsym=<VAR_NAME>=<VAR_VALUE>